# Multiplying vectors in R of different length

Tags: r, vector, cran, vector-multiplication

I have 2 different vectors in R. The entries in the first one are only 0 or 1. The length of the second vector is equal to the number of 1's in the first vector. I want an output that is the first vector but with the 1's replaced by the entries of the 3rd vector. E.g.

```
v1<-c(1,0,0,1,1)
v2<-c(2,3,4)
```

I want:

```
v3<-c(2,0,0,3,4)
```

The length of v1 will be 10 in my script and I have over 1000 to compute so it is not possible to do it manually. Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Jonny

Comment: I think there's no need for multiplication since v1 is binary. `v1[v1 != 0] <- v2`. Or better as @AnandaMahto commented `v1[v1 == 1] <- v2`

Comment: But `Recycling` works if the length of the second vector is NOT equal to the number of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested, you can do:

```
v1[as.logical(v1)] <- v2
```

but it has the disadvantage of overwriting `v1`. If you don't want that, you can do:

```
v3 <- replace(v1, as.logical(v1), v2)
```

Or this one, which is a little more obscure:

```
v3 <- `[<-`(v1, as.logical(v1), v2)
```